# Variable in Parentheses C++

Tags: c++, random, parentheses

I am currently in the process of writing up a C++ program that randomly chooses roles for people using file input/output.

I am almost done, and I build often to make sure my code is working and not psuedocode. I received an error on my snippet of code -

```
randomPrefs.open ("Preferences/"members[random]"-Preferences");
```

I am trying to access the text file in Preferences/foo-Preferences, and the variable is made random by some code above it. I have couted the random snippet and it works perfectly, so I need not include it here. The error I get is :

```
Avalon - Omnipotent.cpp:61:21: error: unable to find string literal operator 'operator""members' with 'const char [13]', 'unsigned int' arguments
```

And so, I have searched around for this error but have found nothing. I thought of making a mini-parentheses around it, and it resulted in a different error -
    Avalon - Omnipotent.cpp:61:51: error: expression cannot be used as a function

Any help would be appreciated.

A little note down here, when not having the parentheses around it, I get a warning about my variable not being used -

```
Avalon - Omnipotent.cpp:39:21: warning: unused variable 'members' [-Wunused-variable]
```

However, the second error does not give a warning about the unused variable.

Hey is what my variable looks like:

```
 unsigned const char members[22] =
```

And I assigned the value "random" which selects a random number from 0 - 21 and I assign the number generated to value random, and declare the variable as members[random]. It works perfectly, I just need help with these errors.

Help!

Comment: members array is a unsigned const char.
The members array is full of a,b,c which I assign to real life names. The code is supposed to be interchanged easily, and that is why I use chars instead of names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To concatenate strings, do the following:

```
std::string s = std::string("Preferences/") + members[random] + "-Preferences";
randomPrefs.open(s);
```

If you don't want the intermediate named variable, then:

```
randomPrefs.open(std::string("Preferences/") + members[random] + "-Preferences");
```

If members doesn't contain characters like `'A'`, `'B'`, `'C'`, or `'4'`, and instead contains the number `4`, `28`, or `153`, then you can convert the number to the appropriate string by using `std::to_string`.

```
std::string s = std::string("Preferences/") + std::to_string(members[random]) + "-Preferences");
```

The warning about the unused variable isn't useful, and is due to the compiler seeing earlier errors in your code. If you fix the above, that should also go away.

Comment: Instead of 
  randomPrefs.open ("Preferences/"members[random]"-Preferences");

I should use  
randomPrefs.open (s); ?

Comment: I get quite a bit of errors when I used your method.
Can you paste it again, but with

iostream and namespace std in place?

Comment: I've got nothing major here, but its worth noting that: in your first example `std::string("Preferences/") + members[random] + "-Preferences";` Works because of Left-to-Right associativity of `+`, so: `std::string + char + const char*` --> `(std::string + char) --> std::string + const char*` ...WOrks! ... Some other arrangment will compile fine with a funny bug of `const char* + char` which compiles because you are presumably adding a `pointer` and an `integer`(promoted)

Comment: `std::string("Preferences/")` can be just `"Preferences/"` on the last line.

Comment: Doing a "cout << s;" after your bit of code doesn't output anything to the console..

Comment: Instead of writing `std::string("Preferences/")` you can write `"Preferences/"s`, this requires adding `using namespace std::string_literals;`

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to do string concatenation, it is probably best to use `itoa() -> std::string(const char*)` or `to_string()` for the number to string, and use `operator+()` or `std::string.append()` to do concatenation.

Note that `to_string()` is C++11:

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/eb3677d7abffca00

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string str1 = "Hello ";
    int i = 2;
    std::string str2 = " World!";

    std::string output = "";
    output.append(str1).append(std::to_string(i)).append(str2);
    std::cout << output << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So, what you're saying is I should precompile my declaration for the parentheses () into a variable foo and when in my parentheses, just use the variable like (foo) and it should work?

Comment: Where does OP needs int to string, conversion? He needs a basic string concatenation.

Comment: @YoBro You're trying to use a syntax that doesn't work. If you were to implement `operator""` it may work but simple, out-of-the-box string concatenation usually requires `std::string` and its `append()` operation. Convert all arguments to `std::string`, then concatenate.

Comment: @marcinj The error for the first line of code is for `"Preferences/"members[random]` which is an overload for `operator""(const char[] lhs, int rhs)`. He is trying to append an `int` to a `const char*`.

Comment: @VermillionAzure: It is fairly unlikely that they intended to use `operator""`, and instead were likely just trying to concatenate two strings and a char.

Comment: Right, I missed that

Answer (score 0):

@YoBro: HERE! – Bill Lynch 7 mins ago

Modelling a bit of my code after his made it work!

```
 std::string s = std::string("Preferences/") + std::to_string(members[random]) + "-Preferences";
  randomPrefs.open(s);
```

I now use something similar to that.

Comment: `std::string("Preferences/")` can be just `"Preferences/"`.

Comment: Without the parentheses () my error console spams out.